# How to write this ActiveRecord Query using Join instead of subquery in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #this user is the event owner
  has_many :members
end

class Members < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Now, I need to list all the members for which `current_user` is the owner. so I have come up with this:

```
@members = Member.where event_id: current_user.events
```

which produces the following query:

```
SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."event_id" IN (SELECT "events"."id" FROM "events" WHERE "events"."user_id" = 1)
```

This works as expected but uses subqueries instead of `JOIN`. Does anyone know a better way to write this same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a has_many :through association to your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :members, :through => :events
end
```

Now you can query for all a user's members through the members association:

```
user.members
```

The SQL generated will look something like:

```
SELECT "members".* FROM "members" INNER JOIN "events" ON "members"."id" = "events"."member_id" WHERE "events"."user_id" = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Transformed to JOIN syntax (with table aliases to make it shorter and easier to read):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM   events e
JOIN   members m ON m.event_id = e.id
WHERE  e.user_id = $1
```

Comment: How can I generate this using `ActiveRecord`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work.

```
Member.joins(:event).where("events.user_id = ?" , current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

```
Member.joins(:event).where(events: {user_id: current_user.id})
```